# How can i refresh Eclipse Package explorer with java code?

Tags: java, eclipse

In my project i generate some files. But everytime i need to refresh Eclipse Package Explorer.

So i need refresh explorer by java code. is This posibble ?

Comment: Provide more details. How are you generatingthese files?

Comment: i generete files from xpand and they created under Explorer. And If i want to see these file everytime i must refresh Explorer. So there is way to auto refresh package explorer with java code ? or this is posibble ?

Answer (score 6):

If you use ANT to generate your files you may configure "External Tool Configuration" to refresh project at completion.

[image]

You may use the native refresh option too:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Window - Preferences - General - Workspace - Refresh using native hooks or polling.